# How do I get the value of the ID of a table row that the user clicks and put it into a hidden field?

Tags: jquery

When a user clicks on a row I want to pull specific information from that row and populate labels and input controls. How do I get the value of the cell of a table row clicked and put it in a label using jQuery?

```
<table id="searchTable" class="display JColResizer">
    <thead><tr class="tableHeader" style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);">
        <td style="width: 99px;">Parcel</td>
        <td style="width: 80px;">Account</td>
        <td style="width: 158px;">Owner</td>
        <td style="width: 158px;">In Care Of</td>
        <td style="width: 158px;">Situs Address</td>
        <td style="width: 158px;">Situs City, State, Zip</td>
        <td style="width: 158px;">Mailing Address</td>
        <td style="width: 158px;">Mailing City, State, Zip</td>
        <td style="width: 158px;">Reponse Code</td>
        <td style="width: 158px;">Initial Mail Date</td>
        <td style="width: 160px;">Reclass Mail Date</td>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr id="123">
        <td>21753566</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10101 N ARABIAN TRAIL LLC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10101 N ARABIAN TR 2023</td>
        <td>SCOTTSDALE AZ  85258</td>
        <td>5 TRENTON CT </td>
        <td>SOUTH BARRINGTON IL  60010</td>
        <td>Qualified Family Member</td>
        <td>2013-03-21</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="234">
        <td>21753566</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10101 N ARABIAN TRAIL LLC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10101 N ARABIAN TR 2023</td>
        <td>SCOTTSDALE AZ  85258</td>
        <td>5 TRENTON CT </td>
        <td>SOUTH BARRINGTON IL  60010</td>
        <td>Qualified Family Member</td>
        <td>2013-03-21</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="345">
        <td>21753566</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10101 N ARABIAN TRAIL LLC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10101 N ARABIAN TR 2023</td>
        <td>SCOTTSDALE AZ  85258</td>
        <td>5 TRENTON CT </td>
        <td>SOUTH BARRINGTON IL  60010</td>
        <td>Qualified Family Member</td>
        <td>2013-03-21</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr></tbody>           
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/oypu8Lmz/

```
$('#mytable tr').click(function(){
    //finding all cell in clicked row
    $(this).find('td').each(function(ind,obj){
        //set cell value in input
        $('.cell').eq(ind).val($(this).text());
    })
})
```

Comment: Awesome! Just what I was looking for! How would I store into an array instead? Is that possible? Thank you soo much!!! :)

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/oypu8Lmz/4/ I do not know exactly what you need

Comment: What does the "ind" in the function(ind) mean/do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting an onclick for all td elements?

```
<input type="text" id="textInput">    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td onclick="fieldClicked(this);">Contents</td>
            <td onclick="fieldClicked(this);">Whatever</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And then a javascript function like:

```
function fieldClicked(target)
{
    $("#textInput").val($(target).html());
}
```

Or say you want the values of both td elements from a row if the user clicks on a row:

```
<input type="text" id="textInput">    
<table>
    <tr onclick="rowClicked(this);">
        <td>FirstName</td>
        <td>LastName</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With a javascript function like:

```
function rowClicked(target) 
{
    var firstName = $(target).children("td").eq(0).html();
    var lastName = $(target).children("td").eq(1).html(); 
    $("#textInput").val("Selected name is: "+firstName+" "+lastName); 
}
```